# Error during saving build definition on RTC using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, build, continuous-integration, rational-team-concert, ibm-jazz

I am using Jenkins version 2.222.1 with EWM version 7.0 (Formerly known as RTC). When I am trying to save a build definition created in RTC I am getting this error.[image: Error on saving build definition after selecting the job from Jenkins]

I have checked the test connection was successful while creating build engine in RTC.[image]

Comment: I explored configure security settings in Jenkins and there i configured with project based matrix settings but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar [to this issue](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/229701/build-jenkins-rtc602-error-expected-code-200-ok-but-received-code-403-with-message-forbidden):

- either the user for the test connection is not the same as the one used to access Jenkins Job in the RTC build definition
- or it is, but without the right, on Jenkins permission matrix, to view jobs
- or the user is Jenkins admin and has all the right anyway, but the Jenkins logs might include something like "`WARNING hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter#doFilter: No valid crumb was included in request for ... by <aUser>: Returning 403`"

The last case is an actual [RTC issue](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=493071), to be fixed with RTC 7.x (and seen with Jenkins 2.190 or later)

Comment: Issue is similar to the one you shared, and as per that I have already tried CHECK CSRF:
" An immediate solution (workaround or actual fix depending on your security requirements) is the following:
- as a jenkins administrator, uncheck the 'csrf protection' box of the 'configureSecurity' administration web page ("Manage Jenkins"->"Configure Global Security").
- request a new rtc build."

User is also same 
Jenkins permission matrix i will have to see.